# Python Selenium element not visible in pop-up window

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Not sure why I am receiving the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I am attempting to click on the Box Score link after clicking on the 'More' button for each game (each game that does not have a GT link for that matter). Am I having issues because this button is showing in a pop-up type window?

I have attempted to resolve the situation by using time.sleep(5) or so, however the same error prints to the screen, so it does not seem to be an issue of waiting for the link to load/appear.

Here is my code:

```
schedule = 'http://www.gamecocksonline.com/sports/m-basebl/sched/scar-m-basebl-sched.html'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(schedule)

#Find 'More' button, scroll to, and click
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='sch-view-more']")[idx]
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", python_button)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -150);")
python_button.click()

#Click on Box Score link
python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Box Score']")
python_button.click()

#Pass HTML to Beautiful Soup and close browser window
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
playbyplay(soup) #Reads info from the html
driver.quit()
```

Comment: When I use chrome to "Inspect Element" and copy xpath, I get the value different than yours. For example `//*[@id="2020541"]/td[6]/a`, `//*[@id="2020542"]/td[6]/a` .... and so on for the "More" element

Comment: FYI, the first 'More' element that I am interested in is the first game against Clemson (because it is the first game without a GT link associated with it). Probably the reason for the difference

Comment: At which line are you trying to click `Box Score link`?

Comment: I should mention that all of this is inside a for loop that iterates based on idx. And the two lines below the comment that mentions the box score link

Comment: If I am not wrong there are 2 `Box Score` which one do you want to click and whats that `[idx]` all about??

Comment: I am only seeing 1 Box Score, could you point out the other for me? The one I see is under <span class="sch-event-related">. The [idx] pertains to an outer for loop that I did not include in the cited code (it essentially iterates through the entire schedule and triggers one of two codes: one redirects to the GameTracker link if it is available and the other clicks on the box score - the code that pertains to this question)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my own issue here (thanks to @DebanjanB for pointing out a few things in the comments).

Adding a wait time to allow for the links to become available, as well as observing that the games at the top of the page follow the same xpath as the one I was searching for were the main resolutions.

```
#Click on Box Score link
time.sleep(1)
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='sch-event-related']")[-1]
python_button.click()
```